# Mock: Uninteresting mock function call vith object return

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing program to test my c++ function but I couldn't use mock function that has to return another object. I don't know how to resolve it.

So if somebody can help me.

Each time, I get this message on my result's tests:

```
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: getEventFree()
          Returns: NULL
```

Mock function:

```
class MockXF : iXF
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(Event *, getEventFree, (), (override));
};
```

Button function:

```
class Button
{
public:
    init(*iXF theXF){ixf = theXF}
    start(){ixf->getEventFree(); //Use the event ...}
private:
    iXF* ixf;
};
```

Tests:

```
Event event;
MockXF mockxf;
// will create a segmentation fault which break the test
TEST_F(ButtonTest, Start)
{
  Button button(&mockxf);
  EXPECT_CALL(mockxf, getEventFree()).WillOnce(Return(&event));
  button.start(); //This function called mockxf.getEventFree()
}
```

Comment: Your example does not compile, because `MockXF` inherits privately from `iXF` ([see it online](https://godbolt.org/z/6P6jYY)). Please provide [mcve], because after fixing that the problem [does not reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/cofz9o).

Comment: Yes thanks, but I get each time the same result on vscode

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: getEventFree()
          Returns: NULL